# Regex that matches 4 or more words from a list

Tags: java, python, regex

#### Background

We have a system that maintains a repository of regular expressions and checks some incoming text against these regex's for some filtering purposes. One of the regex's we are trying to build is described below. The solution I am looking for is strictly regex-based due to production constraints.

#### Problem

I have a list of words: word1, word2, word3, word4, word5, word6, word7, word8, word9, word10. I am trying to write a regular expression that matches a string if it contains 4 or more of these words, at any positions in any order.

#### Examples

- "Abc word3 def word2 ghi word7 jkl word1 mno word5" should be a match, since it has more than 4 words from the given list.
- "Abc word2 def ghi word8" shouldn't be a match, since it has only 2 words from the given list.

#### Current State

I have the following regex, but it doesn't seem to do what I need.

```
((?i)((word1)|(word2)|(word3)|(word4)|(word5)|(word6)|(word7)|(word8)|(word9)|(word10))\b){4,}
```

Any suggestions please, in either Java or Python notation?

Edit: Added some background information.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @Marat: We have a system that maintains a repository of regular expressions and checks some incoming text against these regex's for some filtering purposes. One of the regex's we are trying to build is what I described. I gave the word list in abstract form, due to confidentiality reasons. But we have a concrete list of words, of which if a piece of text contains 4 or more words we 'reject' it.

Comment: complexity of this solution is at least (n choose 4), where n is the number of filter words. I guess it is a great reason to redesign the system to do something besides pure regular expression (e.g. use python sets)

Comment: @Marat: Thanks for the suggestion. We will keep that in mind.

Comment: When a comment asks for clarification of the question it's always best to edit the question rather than to elaborate in comments. For one, not all readers read all comments. Many of those new to SO add something like "Edit:..." as part of their edit. That's unnecessary and a distraction. Just make sure you don't actually change the question, especially if one or more answers have been posted. Incidentally, I question if a regular expression is the best tool for this job, though one may have a place as part of the code.

Comment: If "bad" were one of those words in the list, would this string meet the test: "He was a bad, bad, bad, bad, dude.", or must at least four distinct words match? Why do you want to use a regular expression for this? Why not simply break the string into words and match each against the given list of words, stopping if and when there are four matches?  (You could first convert the list to a set to speed lookups.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland We are fine with counting multiple occurrences of the same word separtely, they don't have to be distinct words. Even though this seems silly in principle, in practice we don't see many cases with duplicate words. The reason why I am seeking a regex is because our production system is some kind of a repository of regex's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex worked for all my tests:

```
(?i)(.*(^|\b)((word1)|(word2)|(word3)|(word4)|(word5)|(word6)|(word7)|(word8)|(word9)|(word10))($|\b).*){4,}
```

They include:

1. "Abc word3 def word2 ghi word7 jkl word1 mno word5" -> true
2. "Abc word2 def ghi word8" -> false
3. "word3 sadasd sadasd word1 word2 word4" -> true
4. "word3 sadasd sadasd word1 word2word4" -> false
5. "aword3 sadasd sadasd word1 word2 word4" -> false
6. "word3 sadasd sadasd word1 word2 word4a" -> false

I think your original regex was missing mainly the `.*` to match any string before and after the keywords.

I also took care to check if it's the beginning of line or a boundary character before a keyword (test 5) wich I think was also missing.

Comment: This is exacly what I am looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use regular expression. If all you're concerned about is the number of occurrences of any word, then you can convert the input list into a `set` and perform an `intersection` operation on it.

```
wrd_list = ["word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5", "word6", "word7", "word8", "word9", "word10"]

s = "Abc word3 def word2 ghi word7 jkl word1 mno word5"

if len(set(wrd_list).intersection(s.split())) > 4:
    print('more than 4 occurrences found')
```

EDIT: This code is in Python

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My usecase requires me to write a regex. We have a system that takes regular expressions and checks certain incoming text for matches on those regular expressions. Let's say it's a hard business requirement in my case -- we need a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this (not regex, but I think more readable):

```
words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4', 'word5', 'word6', 'word7', 'word8', 'word9', 'word10']
text = "Abc word2 def ghi word8"
sum(i in text for i in words)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am looking for a regex. That's a hard business constraint we have -- regex only solution.